# "Open Neutral" only when load applied- my tester is confusing me

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, neutral

I have a 20amp circuit with a 20amp GFI and 4 more 15amp outlets after it.  With nothing plugged in, they all indicate (on my 3-light tester) they are wired correctly.  As soon as 1 thing is plugged in anywhere they all indicate an open neutral, including the starting GFI.

I have replaced the GFI, then the breaker with no change, I have inspected the line from the box to the GFI but no loose wiring.  This circuit had been working fine using an 1100w microwave on the second outlet, occasionally using other small kitchen appliances here and the GFI.

The only thing new is we started running a clothing washer on the fourth outlet.  It ran fine for a good month or so before this issue started, and it is running off a similar circiut just fine.  So not sure if it is related or not.  At a loss what to do, was going to pull breaker again to inspect connection and possibly replace again.  Need suggestions.

Comment: If the neutral is open the breaker won't help that is the hot. in cases like this I look for back stabs they can look good but not making contact inside. Also a loose wire nut or broken wire. Since you said neutral focus on the white wires at the plugs or where the wire is terminated in the panel at the bus.

Comment: Are you using a three prong tester to test the circuit? Since these devices really don't put a load on the circuit it is possible you have a partial connection that looks good to the tester but will not carry any appreciable current. I agree with Ed Beal you should recheck the connections in any of the boxes that you opened and worked in. Especially the neutral connections.

Comment: I suggested an edit to make clear that you are referring to the *descriptive legends on a 3-light tester*, which can be a bit like a magic 8-ball sometimes. You described it like it was official/true.

Comment: Yes i am using a three prong tester, and what you say makes sense I will check the outlet connections again especially at the GFI.

Comment: Just one light on the tester, correct?  You'd expect with a poor connection someplace, plugging something in would pull the neutral up to hot which would illuminate two lights.  Putting an actual volt meter between neutral and ground might be enlightening.